# PNAccessDeniedCategory for sending the message in pubnub objective c

Tags: objective-c, pubnub

I am trying to send the message by using pubnub. 
But it gives me error for : PNAccessDeniedCategory
I am not finding any solution how to solve this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@"pub-c-..."subscribeKey:@"sub-c-..."];
    self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
    //Subscription process results arrive to listener which should adopt to PNObjectEventListener protocol and registered using:
    [self.client addListener:self];

    //Listeners callbacks:
    [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"test123"] withPresence:YES];
    NSLog(@"channel-->%@",self.client.channels);
    configuration.uuid = @"test123";

}
- (void)client:(PubNub *)client didReceiveStatus:(PNSubscribeStatus *)status {

    if (status.category == PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory) {
        // This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost
    }

    else if (status.category == PNConnectedCategory) {

        // Connect event. You can do stuff like publish, and know you'll get it.
        // Or just use the connected event to confirm you are subscribed for
        // UI / internal notifications, etc

    }
    else if (status.category == PNReconnectedCategory) {

        // Happens as part of our regular operation. This event happens when
        // radio / connectivity is lost, then regained.
    }
    else if (status.category == PNDecryptionErrorCategory) {

        // Handle messsage decryption error. Probably client configured to
        // encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.
    }else if (status.category == PNAccessDeniedCategory) {
     Nslog(@"It gives me this error");

  }
}
```

Please advice. Whether this error is because my account is expired and that is the reason it is not allowing me to access ?
Do i have to create another free account ? or have to create new key ?
Please help.

Comment: You need to update your question with details about the error and point out which line is causing it.

Comment: Answer below. I also edited your code to remove the full pub and sub key value. You shouldn't broadcast these to the world. Ironically, unless you enable Access Manager and grant explicit access to each user :) But likely, you need to disable Access Manager until you have the proper granting logic in place (see below). I would advise disabling this key set and create a new key set.

Answer (score 0):

### PubNub Access Manager

You have [Access Manager add-on enabled on your keys](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/644/how-do-i-enable-add-on-features-for-my-keys) and so it is just doing its job - denying un-granted access to your keys. You must [grant all access to use your keys](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pam-security-sdk-v4) once this is enabled. When you enable Access Manager a dialog pops up with a warning:

> Warning: This action will enable Access Manager on your keyset. If you
> are already using this keyset in a production application, please be
> aware you will need to grant access to all existing channels in order
> to continue use without interruptions.

Here is a snapshot of that dialog:

[image]

You can disable Access Manager until you are ready to implement the proper granting logic on your server and you will no longer get this *error*.

Before you go live with your app, you should implement the necessary granting logic and enable Access Manager to protect your keys from being wrongfully used.